# Add arguments at specific position in a new file

Tags: java, string

How can I create a new file with some constant content while some content being added from command line argument.

The content of my file should look like this:-

```
set chip arg1
set device arg2
set top arg3
set file arg4
```

but in place of every `arg` I want to assign the values taken from user from command line and then saving the file at some loction.

I have tried :-

```
String newFile = +"set chip \n"
+"set device \n"
+"set top \n"
+"set file ";

String chip = System.getProperty("chip");
String device = System.getProperty("device");
String top = System.getProperty("top");
String file = System.getProperty("file");
```

But I don't know how to add the received arguments at specific position.

Comment: why it is down voted? Please give reasons for down voting so that I can improve my questions in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at the [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class:

```
String result = MessageFormat.format( "set chip {0}\n" + 
                                      "set device {1}\n" +
                                      "set top {2}\n" +
                                      "set file {3}" ,
                                      chip , device , top , file );
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29

```
String s = "something %s"
String.format(null, s, "param")
```